# Android: wont let share intent go back

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin

When using share intent to share an Image to text messenger I hit send on the text message with the image and Android returns me to the app I got the shared image from, I would like to stay in messenger instead.

Any way to help solve this problem would be awesome.

The way I keep seeing is by using flags, but this doesnt seem to do anything(not sure if I am using the flags right). I attached my code with the flag method in it, any help/input would be great. Thank you.

```
    val bitmap= (el as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
    val cachePath = File(context.cacheDir, "images")
    cachePath.mkdirs() 
    val stream = FileOutputStream("$cachePath/image.png")
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
    stream.close()
    val imagePath = File(context.cacheDir, "images")

    val newFile = File(imagePath, "image.png")

    val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "REDACTEDPACKAGENAME.fileprovider", newFile)

    val shareIntent = Intent()
    shareIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    shareIntent.setType(activity?.getContentResolver().getType(contentUri))

    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, contentUri)
    shareIntent.flags=Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP

    activity?.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share with:"))
```

Answer (score 0):

To close the current activity use

`finish();`

Comment: Thanks but doesn't really answer my problem